# Not getting success after publish cocoaPod libray push

Tags: cocoapods

pod repo push iOS_FS iOS_FS.podspec

Validating spec
 -> iOS_FS (0.1.0)
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description

And trying to add in my project pod 'iOS_FS'. it's not working saying not available. How get know whether my library has been publish successfully or not.

Comment: [!] Unable to find a specification for `iOS_FS (~> 0.0.1)`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create own iOS cocoa pod. follow below steps.
How to create your own pod file and shared it with other developers.

Create and public own pod.

Step 1:-
Create pod file in a local directory by running the below command.

pod spec create podspecificationfileName

Example: 
pod spec create iOSUtilis

After creating file do configuration of target version, tag, code sync, dependency of other framework.

Step 2: once you make sure your code is compiling and well working
Create tag of your branch like below

git tag 0.0.1

git push origin 0.0.1

And update tag number in iOSUtilis.podspec file
Step 3: run command:

pod spec lint iOSUtilis.podspec

Result will be:

iOSUtilis.podspec passed validation

Step 4: publish you pod to online 
Run command.

pod trunk push iOSUtilis.podspec

Result will be:

---

Congrats

iOSLoader (0.0.1) successfully published
   September 28th, 20:27
   https://cocoapods.org/pods/iOSLoader

### Tell your friends!

MacBook-Pro:iOSUtilis chandrakant$

Answer (score 0):

How to create another version of pod.

Step 1: Just make changes in your code and validate the working.
Step 2. Create another version of tag

git tag 0.0.2

git push origin tag 0.0.2

Step 3. Update new tag version in iOSUtils.podspec
Run command

pod spec lint  iOSUtils.podspec

Still getting error fix

Delete tag

git tag -d tagName

git push origin tagName

Clear cache

pod cache clean --all

Fix error in origin branch and again create tag and do the remaining process when get success  “iOSUtilis.podspec passed validation”

Step 4. Final step

Run command

pod trunk push iOSUtils.podspec